# How to split a Column when you have same values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on splitting a column in the dataframe, the column has similar words but only the last few words are different. I am trying to split the common words in one column and the words that are different is another column.

This is how the dataframe looks like.

```
**Column1**   
InitialCharms::Charm::AAAAAA
InitialCharms::Charm::BBBBBB
InitialCharms::Charm::CCCCCC
InitialCharms::Charm::DDDDDD
InitialCharms::Charm::EEEEEE
InitialCharms::Charm::FFFFFF
InitialCharms::Charm::GGGGGG
InitialCharms::Charm::HHHHHH
InitialCharms::Charm::IIIIII
InitialCharms::Charm::JJJJJJ
InitialCharms::Charm::KKKKKK
InitialCharms::Charm::LLLLLL  

The Expected output:  

**Column1**              **Column2**  
InitialCharms             AAAAA  
InitialCharms             BBBBB  
InitialCharms             CCCCC
```

I am using pandas!

Comment: What about `::Charm::`??

Comment: @yatu Thanks yes it's working I a was initially using "::" and I wasn't able to figure the way to split the column. Both jezrael and Pasindu Gamarachchi solution works.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and if necessary remove second column by `drop`:

```
df1 = df['Column1'].str.split('::', expand=True).drop(1, axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df1 = df['Column1'].str.split('::Charm::', expand=True)
```

---

```
df1.columns = ['Col1','Col2']
print (df1)
             Col1    Col2
0   InitialCharms  AAAAAA
1   InitialCharms  BBBBBB
2   InitialCharms  CCCCCC
3   InitialCharms  DDDDDD
4   InitialCharms  EEEEEE
5   InitialCharms  FFFFFF
6   InitialCharms  GGGGGG
7   InitialCharms  HHHHHH
8   InitialCharms  IIIIII
9   InitialCharms  JJJJJJ
10  InitialCharms  KKKKKK
11  InitialCharms  LLLLLL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working, I am new to python and pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df['NewColumn1'] = df['Column1'].str.split('::').str[0]
df['NewColumn2'] = df['Column1'].str.split('::').str[-1]
```

Comment: I don't think you should split twice.  You can save the intermediate result to avoid duplicating the computation.  I.e., `u = df['Column1'].str.split('::'); u.str[0]; u.str[-1]`